# LinkedHashSet is not Removing Duplicates

Tags: java, collections, set, duplicates, linkedhashset

I am using LinkedHashSet for removing duplicated entries. But for below custom model the Set still keeps duplicate entries. Please help me to find the bugs. Is there anything wrong with overriding equals method. For your kind information i only treats two node equals when their phone, type and status are same.

```
public class BlockNode { 
    public int id;
    public int type;
    public int status;
    public String phone;
    public String date;
    public String content;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this.toString().equals(((BlockNode)o).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "number:" + phone + " type:" + type + " status:" + status + "\n"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to overriding hashCode, also fix the implementation of equals(). It's not supposed to throw an exception if you pass an instance of another class, or null. It must return false in these cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also have to override the method `hashCode`.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return toString().hashCode(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember to override `hashCode` whenever you override `equals`.

Comment: what would be a good hashCode in this case. @Henry

Comment: @Hissain: now is the time to start reading the javadoc of Object.equals() and Object.hashCode(), and figure that out by yourself. Also look at the `Objects` class